# Converting all the columns of dataset to binary (either 0 or 1)

Tags: python, pandas

## Binary conversion of numerical data

I am new to python. I am trying to get the output in the form of 0 and
1 only. Not like 00001 etc. I am trying to keep the values in features
that are 0 as 0 in output and those values which are greater than 0 to
replace them with 1 in all of the dataset's columns. I am
preprocessing my dataset. I am stuck on this part. I have converted
the Nominal features into binary ones already. I am using NSLKDD
dataset.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df.iloc[:,0:] = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:, 0:])
print(df)
```

trying to write down the function but couldn't understand how to
proceed:

```py
def numericalTobinary (datset):
  if (datset > 0):  
    datset.iloc[:,0:]=1
  else:
    datset.iloc[:,0:]=0
```

Comment: Welcome. Have you tried `df.applymap()`? You could do something like `df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to create a function for that. You can use `df > 0` to create a boolean version of your dataframe, and then use `astype` to convert boolean values to integers (1 and 0):

```py
binary_df = (df > 0).astype(int)
```

Comment: This Worked. Thanks.
I am new to python so could you please suggest some material to grab the concepts strongly?

Comment: You're welcome! Could you accept the answer if you are happy with it?

I would suggest the Kaggle tutorials, they are well-written and cover the basis. You can find them here: https://www.kaggle.com/learn/overview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0],[2, 20],[3, 0],[5, 100]]))
print(a)

a.loc[a[1]>0, 1]= 1
print(a)
```

Output before:

```
   0    1
0  1    0
1  2   20
2  3    0
3  5  100
```

Output after:

```
   0  1
0  1  0
1  2  1
2  3  0
3  5  1
```